# Adding 301 redirect to a working RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, apache

I am struggling with what is probably a very easy fix.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sotw/list/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /wp-content/plugins/wp-photocontest/view.php?post_id=$1&order=$2 [L]
```

NOTE: This is a WordPress site using custom permalinks. This URL Rewrite is for a plugin I want to clean up the url.

Old URL : www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-photocontest/view.php?post_id=2049&order=chrono

New URL : www.mywebsite.com/sotw/list/2049/chrono

Anything I link forward to the new url works. But I want to to redirect all of the OLD urls I have tried adding the following to my RewriteRule with no luck.

[R=301,L]
[L,R=301,NC]

What should I try instead?

Comment: So, the thing that's actually responsible for displaying the pages is still WordPress, and you use the rule you posted to allow "pretty" URLS, right? If that's the case, slapping a `[R]` on there won't help at all, you'd need a different rule to redirect people *from* the wp-content URL *to* the "sotw" one.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I should have mentioned I'm on WP with permalinks (added). Are you suggesting I have a separate line that's a Redirect and not a RewriteRule? Almost thinking it may be more efficient to keep my current rule and change the plug-in anchors...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just [R=301] you do not need the L flag as R prevents the rest of the file being checked.